# Args[0] por consola - JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
public static void veureinfo(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException{
      // creem l'objecte
      File origen = new File(filePath);

      /**
       * Si es directori llavors:
       */
      if (origen.isFile()){
```

Básicamente el programa me tome el argumento del programa y lo utiliza.

Pero, ¿y si el argumento quiero darlo por consola? Es decir, ¿se puede pedir con la clase `Scanner`?  La idea es que mi programa sea como el CMD de Windows.. por lo que necesito que el usuario sea quien decida qué argumento quiere buscar y mi programa lo encuentre.

¿Cómo se hace?

```
File ruta = new File ("C/");
File f = new File (ruta, ?????);
```

¿Cómo hago que por Scanner me cree un file?

```
Scanner lector = new Scanner (System.in);
??? = lector.next?????
```

Comment: ¿A qué _argumento_ te refieres? ¿A la ruta del archivo?

Comment: Te refieres al parámetro del que recibe el metodo `veureunfo()`?

Comment: Si, ahora mismo esta hecho de tal forma que el parametro se pone en el programa.
Yo quiero que el usuario sea quien decida que quiere buscar. Igual que seria CMD. Como hago para que el usuario lo introduzca?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

entiendo que pretendes solicitar el fichero al usuario sin necesidad de adjuntarlo como argumento a la hora de ejecutar el programa.

```
<code>java nombre_programa</code>
```

Con la clase Scanner puedes solicitar el nombre del fichero:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Nombre del fichero: ")
String nombre_fichero = sc.nextLine();

File file = new File(nombre_fichero);
```

Ahora debes tener en cuenta que se está utilizando un constructor en concreto del objeto File, por lo que tienes las siguientes posibilidades:

*Supongamos el que fichero es "datos_de_prueba.txt".*

1. Podemos crear el objeto File asociado este fichero en el mismo directorio de trabajo:

   `File file = new File("datos_de_prueba.txt");`
2. Creación del objeto File asociado a este fichero, dentro de un archivo del mismo directorio de trabajo: (Es lo que se conoce como ruta relativa)

   `File file = new File("datos/datos_de_prueba.txt");`
3. Se crea el objeto File asociado este fichero mediante la ruta absoluta:

   `File file = new File("c:/Users/ ... Ruta hasta el directorio de trabajo ... /datos/datos_de_prueba.txt");`

Si omitimos la letra de la unidad se toma por defecto la letra donde esta el proyecto.

Comment: gracias!! nextLine.. he probado mil cosas, no he encontrado por internet! MIL GRACIAS!! <3

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String ...args){

    veureinfo(args[0]);

}
```

De esta forma tendrías que ejecutar el programa desde el cmd de forma:

```
javac nombrearchivo.java
java nombrearchivo "ruta del fichero"
```

Si en cambio lo que quieres es simplemente que el usuario pueda introducir la ruta desde el cmd cuando el programa se está ejecutando, entonces sería:

```
public static void main(String...args){

  System.out.println("Introduzca la ruta del archivo");
  String ruta="";
  Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
  ruta=teclado.nextLine();
  NombreClase.veureinfo(ruta);

}
```

Hablas en el título de args[0] y en la pregunta de scanner son cosas totalmente diferentes, args[] es un array de argumentos tipo string que puede recibir un programa java al ser ejecutado desde consola, añadiendo estos argumentos de la forma que te expliqué arriba y separados por comas cada argumento será un elemento del array args[]. En cambio la clase Scanner se utiliza para que en la ejecución de un programa se permita al usuario introducir cualquier dato por medio del teclado en el momento que utilizes sus métodos.

Answer (score -3):

PHP tiene una variable **especial** que puedes utilizar para acceder a los argumentos si el script se está ejecutando en el terminal.

Accede a ella; `$argv`.

Comment: La pregunta NO indaga por PHP

Comment: Estoy hablando de java.. sorry. Edito..

Comment: En cualquier caso,  tu pregunta siquiera incluye lo que has intentado, solo nos das a conocer una parte de tu programa, ¿a dónde esta tu intento? Este no es el sitio que estás buscando, Esto **no es soporte 24/7**. 

Comment: Y yo estoy preguntando como hacerlo. Mi aporte es el código desde programa. Lo he Intentado con scanner y no lo consigo por eso necesito ayuda.

Comment: @AntonioRamos por favor, lee [Compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) en el centro de ayuda. Y como te recomendaba en otra publicación, lee también [answer]; tus respuestas deberían centrarse en el lenguaje dado y no ser "cámbiate a PHP" porque eso no es factible en muchos casos.